# Scaling multiple images together evenly?

Tags: android, image, scaling

I'm not sure whether I was very clear before when I tried to ask this, and I've been playing around with it without an adequate solution.

Basically, I'm trying to scale a large image that is composed of many smaller images evenly across screens. Right now, I'm just resizing each component based on the ratio of the total large image size and the screen width. This almost works, but for certain resolutions, certain parts will be one pixel off due to pixel rounding, which is very noticeable since the application is supposed to look like one unbroken image (but it has moving parts, so I need it to be separated). For now, I've gone through and found widths that are close enough to the actual common screen width to work and I am resizing them based on that, but if there is a screen width I haven't accounted for, it might not work well. `layout_weight` doesn't work for the same reason - close, but with little misalignments on some resolutions when a dimension is rounded a pixel off from the images around it.

As a concrete example, say I'm making an app that consists of machinery with moving gears. Part of it is static, and other parts of it are animated. I'm using imageviews as buttons. All I need is to resize it to the exact screen width while preserving aspect ratios. How can I do this and make sure it looks consistent across all screen widths without 1px gaps or 1px misalignments? I have multiple resources for various densities, but I need more flexibility than that.

Is this just something I shouldn't do for Android apps? Or should I perhaps break my image into squares or images with compatible aspect ratios? It seems like there must be a simpler solution to this, since all I need is to scale everything linearly based on width.

I hope my question is clear. I'm having a hard time even finding examples of other people doing the same thing.

Comment: what was wrong with my answer for your question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17133401/how-can-i-scale-multiple-images-together-to-preserve-the-size-relationship-betwe

Comment: I had problems getting it to work with my layout and a couple custom classes (but that was with no sleep for 2 days). I'll try it again when my brain is functioning properly and let you know. Thanks!

Comment: first copy the code as it is to your Activity and see if it suits you

Comment: This looks like it might be the solution! I haven't had time to fully play around with it, but I plugged my layout in, and it works. Can I just scale it by using that class in an XML layout file? Is there a way to add the layers to it as XML children? I guess I could always set up new attributes and just have it load multiple sources and get the intrinsic dimensions from each for the offsets if I can't do it that way. Also, how do I set click listeners? Do I just define rectangles based on the positions and use a touch listener? Will that scale? Anyway, this is going to be very useful. Thanks!

Comment: i have enhanced version where layers can be defined in xml but its imho to long to post it here. for listeners: see commented out lines just before setContentView - its a touch listener that lets you drag a layer, notice reverse mapping of matrix